# Skipped 2137 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: android, android-fragment

Всем привет!
Не могу побороть ошибку.
После нескольких обновлений фрагмента (обновляются сразу 4  элемента) вешает его и потом выдает следующее сообщение :

> Skipped 2137 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on
>   its main thread и после этого фрагмент сбрасывает все настройки UI

Код java

```
if (RootTools.isBusyboxAvailable()) {
                if (RootTools.isRootAvailable()) {
                    if (RootTools.isAccessGiven()) {

                        Command command1 = new Command(0,
                                "pgrep rngd") {
                            @Override
                            public void commandOutput(int id, String line) {
                                super.commandOutput(id, line);
                                if (line.matches("[0-9]+"))
                                {

                                            entropystatus = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.entropystatus);
                                            entropystatus.setText("СТАТУС СЕРВИСА: ВКЛЮЧЕН");
                                            entropystatus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundbuttongood);
                                            startentropy = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.startentropy);
                                            startentropy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundbuttonfuck);
                                            startentropy.setEnabled(false);
                                            startentropy.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                                            stopentropy = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.stopentropy);
                                            stopentropy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundbuttoncal);
                                            stopentropy.setEnabled(true);
                                            stopentropy.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                            stopentropy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(View v) {

                                                            if (RootTools.isBusyboxAvailable()) {
                                                                if (RootTools.isRootAvailable()) {
                                                                    if (RootTools.isAccessGiven()) {

                                                                        Command command1 = new Command(0,
                                                                                "entropy_disable");
                                                                        try {
                                                                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Сервис остановлен!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                                            RootTools.getShell(true).add(command1);
                                                                        } catch (IOException | RootDeniedException | TimeoutException ex) {
                                                                            ex.printStackTrace();
                                                                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ОШИБКА. СВЯЖИТЕСЬ С РАЗРАБОТЧИКОМ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                                        }
                                                                    } else {
                                                                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ОШИБКА! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                                    }

                                                                } else {
                                                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ОШИБКА!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                                }
                                                            } else {
                                                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ОШИБКА! НЕ УСТАНОВЛЕН BUSYBOX!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                                RootTools.offerBusyBox(getActivity());
                                                            }


                                                }
                                            });


                                }

                            }
                            @Override
                            public void commandCompleted(int id, int exitcode) {
                                super.commandCompleted(id, exitcode);
                                if (exitcode==1)
                                {
                                    entropystatus = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.entropystatus);
                                    entropystatus.setText("СТАТУС СЕРВИСА: ВЫКЛЮЧЕН");
                                    entropystatus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundbuttonbad);

                                            stopentropy = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.stopentropy);
                                            stopentropy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundbuttonfuck);
                                            stopentropy.setEnabled(false);
                                            stopentropy.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                            startentropy = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.startentropy);
                                            startentropy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundbuttoncal);
                                            startentropy.setEnabled(true);
                                            startentropy.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                            startentropy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(View v){

                                                    if (RootTools.isBusyboxAvailable()) {
                                                        if (RootTools.isRootAvailable()) {
                                                            if (RootTools.isAccessGiven()) {

                                                                Command command1 = new Command(0,
                                                                        "entropy_enabler");
                                                                try {
                                                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Сервис запущен!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                                    RootTools.getShell(true).add(command1);
                                                                } catch (IOException | RootDeniedException | TimeoutException ex) {
                                                                    ex.printStackTrace();
                                                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ОШИБКА. СВЯЖИТЕСЬ С РАЗРАБОТЧИКОМ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                                }
                                                            } else {
                                                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ОШИБКА! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                            }

                                                        } else {
                                                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ОШИБКА!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                        }
                                                    } else {
                                                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ОШИБКА! НЕ УСТАНОВЛЕН BUSYBOX!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                        RootTools.offerBusyBox(getActivity());
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            });

                                        }

                            }
                        };

                        try {
                            RootTools.getShell(true).add(command1);
                        } catch (IOException | RootDeniedException | TimeoutException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else {
                    }

                } else {
                }
            } else {
                RootTools.offerBusyBox(getActivity());
            }
```

Код layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/entropystatus"
        android:layout_weight="0.04"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center|center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Entropy Generator позволяет ускорить работу устройства путем выполнения специальных операций в /dev/random. Учтите, что данная утилита действительно полезна только для старых версий Android (ниже 4.4), на Android 4.4-6.0 она, естественно, работает, но существенного эффекта прироста производительности Вы скорее всего не заметите"
        android:id="@+id/textView33" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Сначала, если требуется, установите библиотеку по работе с Entropy, потом чтобы включить Entropy Generator, нажмите соответствующую кнопку\n\n"
        android:id="@+id/textView35" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="330dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:text="Установить библиотеку работы с Entropy Generator\n"
        android:id="@+id/entropy"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center|center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Статус кнопки обновляется только после перезагрузки страницы"
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center|center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="10dp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.03">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="162dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Запустить сервис"
            android:id="@+id/startentropy"
            android:layout_weight="0.04"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="159dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Остановить сервис"
            android:id="@+id/stopentropy"
            android:layout_weight="0.04"
            android:layout_gravity="right|top" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="322dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Удалить Entropy Generator из системы"
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.04"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Пробовал вешать изменения UI каждого элемента на:

```
 getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {


    }
});
```

не помогает.

Comment: Мне кажется сообщение наоборот говорит что слишком много работы в главном потоке,  но его все обычно игнорируют.

Comment: Так же пробовал перераспределить работу через runOnUiThread, не помогает(

Comment: Ну я недавно начал заниматься такой разработкой, с потоками еще толком не знаком, уж извиняйте если немного не так делаю)

Comment: Скажем так из главного потока нельзя ничего вызывать стороннего никакой сети( это сам андроид не даст уже) и вообще ничем его не грузить кроме взаимодействия с пользователем. Конечно бывают исключения но редко.

Answer (score 2):

Вынесите всю тяжелую работу в [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)  [тыц](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/149-urok-86-asynctask-znakomstvo-neslozhnyj-primer.html) [тыц](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/150-urok-87-asynctask-parametry-promezhutochnye-rezultaty.html) и [тыц](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/asynctask.php)

Однако асинктаски в последнее время используют все реже и реже, всвязи с тем что результат уйдет в "удаленное" активити, если, например, во время работы пользователь повернет экран и по многим другим причинам

Потому рекомендую обратить внимание на [Chronos](https://habrahabr.ru/company/redmadrobot/blog/263111/)
Есть подробное wiki по использованию библиотечки [здесь](https://github.com/RedMadRobot/Chronos/wiki/Broadcasting-results)

Comment: Спасибо! А что скажите насчет Handler или runOnUiThread? Просто они более привлекательны, не нужно создавать доп.классы, описывать в нескольких методах, как например в AsyncTask и в Chronos

Comment: метод runOnUiThread, как следует из названия вам воообще не подходит, так как выпоняет код Ui потоке
Handler всего лишь позволяет управлять очереью событий и по умолчанию так же работает у Ui потоке. Для того чтобы выполнить код в новом потоке смотрите в сторону Runnable, если вам не нужно после работы передавать результат в IU  или  asynctask, если нужно. Но я бы рекоменовал использовать Chronos.

Comment: еще милее сайта не видел:D

Comment: Я бы вам еще посоветовал IntentService каждый таск выполняется в новом потоке, результаты можно возвращать с помощью BroadcastReceiver