# Проблема с ASyncTask- некорректно выполняется код

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Всем привет!

Такая проблема. Использую ASyncTask для выполнения тяжелой операции, которая непосильна основному потоку (была уже моя тема про это: [Skipped 2137 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/548041/skipped-2137-frames-the-application-may-be-doing-too-much-work-on-its-main-thre#comment700686_548041))

Но возникла такая проблема. В коде вроде бы как все правильно, ошибок никаких не выдает, но код должным образом не работает

Значит имеется интерфейс. После того как пользователь, используя Navigation Drawer зайдет в нужный фрагмент, моментально должен выполняться ASyncTask (third в коде). Он запрашивает рут права и проверяет, запущена ли системная служба (команда pgrep rngd), в данном случае служба Entropy. Все это выполняется в OnBackground. После проверки он должен в этом же onBackground присвоить переменной oneperem значение 1, если служба запущена, или же 0, если служба не запущена.
После этого процесс должен перейти в стадию onPostExecute, где осуществляется обработка результата onBackground- то есть, обновление интерфейса в соответствии со значением oneperem (см.выше). В нем обновляются 3 элемента- TextView, которое показывает, запущена ли служба, а также кнопки "Запустить службу" и "Остановить службу", которые выполняются при определенных условиях (например, если служба запущена, то кнопка "Запустить службу" блокируется и остается активной только кнопка остановки и наоборот).
Но работает это как-то странно.
При запуске фрагмента запускается ASyncTask- запрашиваются права суперпользователя, потом в интерфейсе обновляются кнопки и статус службы. НО почему-то статус службы всегда "Служба не запущена", хотя в системе она запущена. А вот после нажатия кнопки "Запустить службу" выдает toast о том, что служба запущена (хотя в реальности служба и так запущена), а после обновления фрагмента (после того как я перезайду в него), ASyncTask вообще или не выполняется, или выполняется через 15 секунд, с аналогичным результатом.
При этом в логе ошибок нет, код вроде как на мой взгляд написан корректно.
Надеюсь что кто-нибудь поможет решить проблему, ибо не знаю то уже и делать....

***Код AsyncTask***

```
public class Wrapper
   {
       public int oneperem;
   }

public class third extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Wrapper> {

    private Context mContext;
    private View rootView;
    public Button startentropy, stopentropy;
    public TextView entropystatus;

    public third(Context context, View rootView){
        this.mContext=context;
        this.rootView=rootView;
    }
    @Override
    public Wrapper doInBackground(String... args) {
       final Wrapper w = new Wrapper();

        if (RootTools.isAccessGiven()) {

            Command command1 = new Command(0,
                    "pgrep rngd") {
                @Override
                public void commandOutput(int id, String line) {
                    super.commandOutput(id, line);
                    if (line.matches("[0-9]+")) {
                        w.oneperem = 1;
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void commandCompleted(int id, int exitcode) {
                    super.commandCompleted(id, exitcode);
                    if (exitcode == 1) {
                        w.oneperem = 0;
                    }

                }
            };

            try {
                RootTools.getShell(true).add(command1);
            } catch (IOException | RootDeniedException | TimeoutException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
        }

        return w;

    }
    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Wrapper w) {

                if (w.oneperem == 1) {
                    entropystatus = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.entropystatus);
                    entropystatus.setText("СТАТУС СЕРВИСА: ВКЛЮЧЕН");
                    entropystatus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundbuttongood);
                    startentropy = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.startentropy);
                    startentropy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundbuttonfuck);
                    startentropy.setEnabled(false);
                    startentropy.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                    stopentropy = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.stopentropy);
                    stopentropy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundbuttoncal);
                    stopentropy.setEnabled(true);
                    stopentropy.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    stopentropy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                    if (RootTools.isAccessGiven()) {

                                        Command command1 = new Command(0,
                                                "entropy_disable");
                                        try {
                                            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Сервис остановлен!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            RootTools.getShell(true).add(command1);
                                        } catch (IOException | RootDeniedException | TimeoutException ex) {
                                            ex.printStackTrace();

                                            Toast.makeText(mContext, "ОШИБКА, СВЯЖИТЕСЬ С РАЗРАБОТЧИКОМ!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    } else
                                    {
                                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "ОШИБКА!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }

                        }
                    });
                }
                if (w.oneperem == 0) {
                    entropystatus = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.entropystatus);
                    entropystatus.setText("СТАТУС СЕРВИСА: ВЫКЛЮЧЕН");
                    entropystatus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundbuttonbad);

                    stopentropy = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.stopentropy);
                    stopentropy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundbuttonfuck);
                    stopentropy.setEnabled(false);
                    stopentropy.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    startentropy = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.startentropy);
                    startentropy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundbuttoncal);
                    startentropy.setEnabled(true);
                    startentropy.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    startentropy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                    if (RootTools.isAccessGiven()) {

                                        Command command1 = new Command(0,
                                                "entropy_enabler");
                                        try {
                                            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Сервис запущен!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            RootTools.getShell(true).add(command1);
                                        } catch (IOException | RootDeniedException | TimeoutException ex) {
                                            ex.printStackTrace();
                                            Toast.makeText(mContext, "ОШИБКА, СВЯЖИТЕСЬ С РАЗРАБОТЧИКОМ!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "ОШИБКА!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }

                        }
                    });
                }

        }
    }
```

***Код запуска ASyncTask***

```
 Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(
            new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Context cont=getActivity();
                    if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ) {
                        new third(cont, view ).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
                    } else {
                        new third(cont, view ).execute();
                    }

                }
            }, 1);
```

***Полный код EntropyFragment***

```
package com.nowenui.systemtweaker.fragments;


 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.graphics.Color;
 import android.os.AsyncTask;
 import android.os.Build;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.os.Handler;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.Toast;
 import com.nowenui.systemtweaker.R;
 import com.stericson.RootShell.exceptions.RootDeniedException;
 import com.stericson.RootShell.execution.Command;
 import com.stericson.RootTools.RootTools;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

public class EntropyFragment extends Fragment {

private Button entropy, delete;


public static EntropyFragment newInstance(Bundle bundle) {
    EntropyFragment messagesFragment = new EntropyFragment();

    if (bundle != null) {
        messagesFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    }

    return messagesFragment;
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_entropy, parent, false);



    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(
            new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Context cont=getActivity();
                    if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ) {
                        new third(cont, view ).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
                    } else {
                        new third(cont, view ).execute();
                    }

                }
            }, 1);




    entropy = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.entropy);
    entropy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundbuttoncal);
    entropy.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    File f = new File("/system/xbin/rngd");
    if (f.exists()) {
        entropy.setEnabled(false);
        entropy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundbuttonfuck);
        entropy.setText("Необходимые библиотеки уже установлены. \nУстановка не требуется, просто пользуйтесь");
    } else {

        entropy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (RootTools.isBusyboxAvailable()) {
                    if (RootTools.isRootAvailable()) {
                        if (RootTools.isAccessGiven()) {

                            Command command1 = new Command(0,
                                    "cp /sdcard/Android/data/com.nowenui.systemtweaker/files/rngd /system/xbin/rngd",
                                    "chmod 755 /system/xbin/rngd",
                                    "cp /sdcard/Android/data/com.nowenui.systemtweaker/files/entro /system/xbin/entro",
                                    "chmod 755 /system/xbin/entro",
                                    "cp /sdcard/Android/data/com.nowenui.systemtweaker/files/entropy_enabler /system/bin/entropy_enabler",
                                    "chmod 777 /system/bin/entropy_enabler",
                                    "cp /sdcard/Android/data/com.nowenui.systemtweaker/files/entropy_disable /system/bin/entropy_disable",
                                    "chmod 777 /system/bin/entropy_disable");
                            try {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Необходимые файлы установлены!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                RootTools.getShell(true).add(command1);
                            } catch (IOException | RootDeniedException | TimeoutException ex) {
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ОШИБКА. СВЯЖИТЕСЬ С РАЗРАБОТЧИКОМ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ОШИБКА! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ОШИБКА!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ОШИБКА! НЕ УСТАНОВЛЕН BUSYBOX!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    RootTools.offerBusyBox(getActivity());
                }

            }
        });
    }


        return view;
}

public class Wrapper
{
    public int oneperem;
}

public class third extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Wrapper> {

    private Context mContext;
    private View rootView;
    public Button startentropy, stopentropy;
    public TextView entropystatus;

    public third(Context context, View rootView){
        this.mContext=context;
        this.rootView=rootView;
    }
    @Override
    public Wrapper doInBackground(String... args) {
       final Wrapper w = new Wrapper();

        if (RootTools.isAccessGiven()) {

            Command command1 = new Command(0,
                    "pgrep rngd") {
                @Override
                public void commandOutput(int id, String line) {
                    super.commandOutput(id, line);
                    if (line.matches("[0-9]+")) {
                        w.oneperem = 1;
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void commandCompleted(int id, int exitcode) {
                    super.commandCompleted(id, exitcode);
                    if (exitcode == 1) {
                        w.oneperem = 0;
                    }

                }
            };

            try {
                RootTools.getShell(true).add(command1);
            } catch (IOException | RootDeniedException | TimeoutException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
        }

        return w;

    }
    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Wrapper w) {

                if (w.oneperem == 1) {
                    entropystatus = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.entropystatus);
                    entropystatus.setText("СТАТУС СЕРВИСА: ВКЛЮЧЕН");
                    entropystatus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundbuttongood);
                    startentropy = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.startentropy);
                    startentropy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundbuttonfuck);
                    startentropy.setEnabled(false);
                    startentropy.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                    stopentropy = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.stopentropy);
                    stopentropy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundbuttoncal);
                    stopentropy.setEnabled(true);
                    stopentropy.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    stopentropy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                    if (RootTools.isAccessGiven()) {

                                        Command command1 = new Command(0,
                                                "entropy_disable");
                                        try {
                                            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Сервис остановлен!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            RootTools.getShell(true).add(command1);
                                        } catch (IOException | RootDeniedException | TimeoutException ex) {
                                            ex.printStackTrace();

                                            Toast.makeText(mContext, "ОШИБКА, СВЯЖИТЕСЬ С РАЗРАБОТЧИКОМ!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    } else
                                    {
                                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "ОШИБКА!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }

                        }
                    });
                }
                if (w.oneperem == 0) {
                    entropystatus = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.entropystatus);
                    entropystatus.setText("СТАТУС СЕРВИСА: ВЫКЛЮЧЕН");
                    entropystatus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundbuttonbad);

                    stopentropy = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.stopentropy);
                    stopentropy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundbuttonfuck);
                    stopentropy.setEnabled(false);
                    stopentropy.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    startentropy = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.startentropy);
                    startentropy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundbuttoncal);
                    startentropy.setEnabled(true);
                    startentropy.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    startentropy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                    if (RootTools.isAccessGiven()) {

                                        Command command1 = new Command(0,
                                                "entropy_enabler");
                                        try {
                                            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Сервис запущен!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            RootTools.getShell(true).add(command1);
                                        } catch (IOException | RootDeniedException | TimeoutException ex) {
                                            ex.printStackTrace();
                                            Toast.makeText(mContext, "ОШИБКА, СВЯЖИТЕСЬ С РАЗРАБОТЧИКОМ!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "ОШИБКА!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }

                        }
                    });
                }

        }
    }

}
```

***Код Layout***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/entropystatus"
        android:layout_weight="0.04"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center|center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Entropy Generator позволяет ускорить работу устройства путем выполнения специальных операций в /dev/random. Учтите, что данная утилита действительно полезна только для старых версий Android (ниже 4.4), на Android 4.4-6.0 она, естественно, работает, но существенного эффекта прироста производительности Вы скорее всего не заметите"
        android:id="@+id/textView33" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Сначала, если требуется, установите библиотеку по работе с Entropy, потом чтобы включить Entropy Generator, нажмите соответствующую кнопку\n\n"
        android:id="@+id/textView35" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="330dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:text="Установить библиотеку работы с Entropy Generator\n"
        android:id="@+id/entropy"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center|center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Статус кнопки обновляется только после перезагрузки страницы"
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center|center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="10dp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.03">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="162dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Запустить сервис"
            android:id="@+id/startentropy"
            android:layout_weight="0.04"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="159dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Остановить сервис"
            android:id="@+id/stopentropy"
            android:layout_weight="0.04"
            android:layout_gravity="right|top" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="322dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Удалить Entropy Generator из системы"
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.04"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: честно скажу, лень читать, очень много текста. Думаю, не мне одному лень. Локализуйте проблему, сократите текст раз в 5

Comment: я сам не пойму почему код не работает должным образом, то ли не выполняется условия в doBackground, то ли хрен знает что...

Comment: Потому что ответ приходит в callback.  Поток AsyncTask'a не ждёт ответы из callback'если они работают в другом потоке.

Comment: Спасибо! Вот такая реализация callback подойдёт? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15271271/android-callback-asynctask-to-fragmentnot-activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что ответ приходит в callback. Поток AsyncTask'a не ждёт ответы из callback'если они работают в другом потоке.

Если `RootTools.getShell(true).add(command1);` выполняется в отдельном потоке, и после выполнения вызывается только один из callback`ов то можо воспользоваться [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)

Код будет `doInBackground()` будет примерно следующий:

```
@Override
public Wrapper doInBackground(String... args) {
final Wrapper w = new Wrapper();

if (RootTools.isAccessGiven()) {

    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    Command command1 = new Command(0,"pgrep rngd") {
        @Override
        public void commandOutput(int id, String line) {
            super.commandOutput(id, line);
            latch.countDown();
            // остальной код
        }

        @Override
        public void commandCompleted(int id, int exitcode) {
            super.commandCompleted(id, exitcode);
            latch.countDown();
            // остальной код
        }
    };

    try {
        RootTools.getShell(true).add(command1);
        latch.await();
    } catch (IOException | RootDeniedException | TimeoutException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
} else {
}

return w;
}
```

Вызов `latch.await();` заблокирует текущий поток, и разблокирует когда счетчик в `latch` дойдет до 0. Т.к. `doInBackground()` выполняется в отдельной потоке, то его блокировка не приведет к блокировке UI.

Comment: Большое спасибо!!! Завтра буду пробовать!

Comment: @NowenUI немного не туда запихал ```await()```. Он должен быть после запуска команды. Обновил ответ.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Теперь ASyncTask корректно работает, но появилась небольшая проблема. Видимо ASyncTask выполняется только один раз, а надо чтобы он выполнялся при перезагрузке фрагмента. Проявляется это так: я захожу во фрагмент, программа выдает что сервис запущен, я нажимаю на кнопку остановки сервиса, перезахожу во фрагмент, статус обновляется на "выключен". Нажимаю кнопку "Запустить", перезагружаю фрагмент- и ... тупо ничего не происходит, после долгого ожидания (сек 20) программа возвращает что сервис выключен (хотя я нажимал на кнопку включить)

Comment: @NowenUI ну тут могу посоветовать вам залогировать код и посмотреть что происходит. Имейте ввиду что при выходе из фрагмента AsyncTask не завершает работу, а продолжает работать пока не дойдет до конца, а при повторном заходе запустится еще один таск. И еще у вас странный запуск AsyncTask'a - достаточно выполнить только ```new third(cont, view ).execute();``` без всяких там Handler'ов.